# Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?

Tags: css, line-breaks

I'm building a multilingual site, with the owner helping me with some translations.  Some of the displayed phrases need line breaks to maintain the style of the site.

Unfortunately, the owner isn't a computer guy, so if he sees `foo<br />bar` there's the chance he'll modify the data somehow as he's translating.

Is there a CSS solution (besides changing the width) to apply to an element which would break after every word?

(I know I can do this in PHP, but I'm wondering if there's a nifty trick I don't know about in CSS to accomplish the same thing, perhaps in the CJK features.)

**EDIT**

I'll attempt to diagram what's happening:

```
----------------          ----------------
| Short Word   |          | Gargantuan   |
|              |          | Word         |
----------------          ----------------
```

The long word breaks automatically, the short word doesn't.  I want it to look like this:

```
----------------          ----------------
| Short        |          | Gargantuan   |
| Word         |          | Word         |
----------------          ----------------
```

Comment: In HTML, elements do break after every word, when the width of a given element requires it. Do you mean within words?

Comment: @Paul - No, I need a solution that's not based on fixing the width.  The problem is, some phrases are longer and break automatically (like you describe) and some phrases are shorter and don't break, making an inconsistent presentation.

Comment: @Paul - Yes, it's like you describe exactly.  Not harming the layout really, but it could look better.

Comment: you could use word-spacing but it would affect all words.. i Think you cant get around wraping those words in span elements.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Use

```css
.one-word-per-line {
    word-spacing: <parent-width>; 
}

.your-classname{
    width: min-intrinsic;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    display: table-caption;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;
}
```

where `<parent-width>` is the width of the parent element (or an arbitrary high value that doesn't fit into one line). That way you can be sure that there is even a line-break after a single letter. Works with Chrome/FF/Opera/IE7+ (and probably even IE6 since it's supporting word-spacing as well).

Comment: Up-vote well deserved! I even started using this with inline-block non-text elements, it works in a same way clear:right works for floating elements. Really useful if you ever need to center align some element but can't use the usual display:block margin: 0 auto; combination.

Comment: It fails on compass preprocessor, any way to set a value?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The answer is really hard to interpret, but he means: `.parent { word-spacing: 100px; }` where `100px` is the width of the parent element.  The problem is that this solution doesn't work if you have a fluid parent.

Comment: Just set a very high value for word spacing such as `word-spacing: 100000px` and you won't have to worry about the parent being fluid in terms of width. Setting a word spacing of 100% would have made sense (it would have been 100% of the parent width), but values expressed in percentage are not supported for that css property.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I used it in a responsive situation, where at one width I want text in tabs to wrap so they're all the same height: `word-spacing: 2em;`  and at a mobile width I want them to be single-line: `word-spacing: unset;`

Comment: Instead of using an arbitrarily large number on word-spacing, try setting the max-width to parent width as well. This worked well for me.
`.one-word-per-line {
        max-width; <parent-width>;
        word-spacing: <parent-width>; 
    }`

Comment: anyone give an example on jsfiddle

Comment: Definitely, it is the best answer, but if there are three words then it breaks all, like `word-break: break-all;` property.

Comment: Applying just `width: min-content;` solved it for me. thanks

Comment: my ide is flagging `word-spacing: <parent-width>; ` as a deprecated feature -- as is the browser.

Answer (score 191):

The answer given by @HursVanBloob works only with fixed width parent container, but **fails in case of fluid-width containers**.

I tried a lot of properties, but nothing worked as expected. Finally I came to a conclusion that giving **`word-spacing` a very huge value** works perfectly fine.

```
p { word-spacing: 9999999px; }
```

or, for the modern browsers you can use the CSS `vw` unit (visual width in % of the screen size).

```
p { word-spacing: 100vw; }
```

Comment: thats what I will try to!

Comment: Completely breaks with &nbsp; though.

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me that makes the fluid width of the container to go very very high.

Comment: @Onza can you share a fiddle link, showing your issue?

Comment: @Onza it doesn't work that way. You need to define a `width` to your parent wrapper or your content wrapper. The text-fix is working hence bringing your next word on new-line but also using available space because of `text-indent: long value;`. You'll have to define a `width-limit` to it. It's difficult to find real-world use of your scenario. If you have `width` then why to break text.

Comment: Yes I figured, I posted a solution on the bottom for that just it case it works for others, sorry I should've mentioned it earlier.

Comment: it works on modern browsers but will cause issue on IE11 on win7

Answer (score 51):

Try using `white-space: pre-line;`. It creates a line-break wherever a line-break appears in the code, but ignores the extra whitespace (tabs and spaces etc.).

First, write your words on separate lines in your code:

```
<div>Short
Word</div>
```

Then apply the style to the element containing the words.

```
div { white-space: pre-line; }
```

**Be careful** though, every line break in the code inside the element will create a line break. So writing the following will result in an extra line break before the first word and after the last word:

```
<div>
    Short
    Word
</div>
```

There's a great article on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) explaining the other white-space attributes.

Comment: You should explain how `white-space` can be used to answer the question. Sorry, but I don't see how.

Comment: Well the article on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/) explains it fully, so I thought a link would be enough, rather than trying to regurgitate the answer here.

Comment: Ok, so you suggest to put real line breaks in the source, and to use the CSS "`white-space: pre;`" to display those line breaks like a `<pre>` tag would do ? That could work, and a line break should look more natural to translators than a `<br />`. I will try to edit your answer to add it :)

Comment: Exactly. Well actually, `white-space: pre-line;` would probably be more appropriate, since it ignores extra whitespace in your code. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Good, maybe just add `white-space: pre;` for IE 7.

Comment: +1 i have a textfield inside a box, that is centered. with `white-space: pre-ine` this works great, whilst it doesn't work with `word-spacing`. thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 45):

An alternative solution is described on [Separate sentence to one word per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184881/separate-sentence-to-one-word-per-line), by applying `display:table-caption;` to the element

Comment: This actually only groups words based on the width of the longest word.

Comment: Although this can group words on a line it works really well in a lot of situations and doesn't feel as hacky as the massive word spacing option.

Comment: This is the one that worked perfectly for me, nice one!

Comment: It doesn't give any result

Answer (score 28):

If you want to be able to choose from different solutions, in addition to the given answers...

An alternative method is to give the container a width of 0 and to make sure overflow is visible. Then each word will overflow out of it and will be on its own line.

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>Short Word</div>
<hr>
<div>Gargantuan Word</div>
```

Or you can use one of those newly proposed `width` values, provided those still exist by the time you read this.

```css
div {
  width: min-intrinsic;       /* old Chrome, Safari */
  width: -webkit-min-content; /* less old Chrome, Safari */
  width: -moz-min-content;    /* current Firefox */
  width: min-content;         /* current Chrome, Safari; not IE or Edge */
}
```

```html
<div>Short Word</div>
<hr>
<div>Gargantuan Word</div>
```

Comment: Best solution honestly

Comment: width & overlow - great answer

Answer (score 21):

`<span>` is an inline element and I'm adding an `display: inline-block` to give a width to the element `max-width: min-content;`, `min-content` is the value/width of the smallest word in your text/sentance.

If you use `min-content`, the "width" will be your longest word. In this case `Example` is your longer word. But if you have different words like `and if` or few 2/3 char words then this words will fit on the same line.

If you want to keep the on word behavior you can give a fixed width, for example `5px`.

Check more examples in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/claudiuu/pen/WNpBNNQ).

```css
.wrapWord {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="wrapWord">
   Example Word
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Self-contained, works cleanly with flexbox.

Comment: This is a nice solution for what I'm trying to do, which is to make the element as narrow as the longest word will allow without necessarily wrapping after each word. For example, "A charm of hummingbirds" wraps to two lines because "A charm of" fits within the space needed by "hummingbirds".

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is the `word-spacing` property.

Add the `<p>` in a container with a specific size (example `300px`) and after you have to add that size as the value in the word-spacing.

HTML

```
<div>
 <p>Sentence Here</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
 width: 300px;
}

p {
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 word-spacing: 300px;
}
```

In this way, your sentence will be always broken and set in a column, but the with of the paragraph will be dynamic.

***Here an example*** [Codepen](https://codepen.io/coswise/pen/vomvBR)

Answer (score 5):

You can't target each word in CSS. However, with a bit of jQuery you probably could.

With jQuery you can wrap each word in a `<span>` and then CSS set span to `display:block` which would put it on its own line.

In theory of course :P

Comment: Yep, I was afraid of that.  Could do it in PHP too but it seems like an ugly solution.  I was thinking there might be some `:first-child` trick or something out there...

Comment: @Steve: no, CSS selectors currently only allow you to select HTML elements, not text nodes. I had a look at [the CSS 3 Text module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/), but there doesn’t seem to be anything there that forces a break after each word in an element. Mark’s solution is your best bet.

Comment: @Paul, @Mark - If one of you guys wants the rep, you could make that an answer and I'll accept it. I'm going to mark this as unanswerable (for now) per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/48013/what-do-i-do-when-a-question-cant-be-answered.

Comment: I think Mark already has made it an answer, all the rep is his as far as I’m concerned.

Comment: @Paul - +1 team player give the guy a badge or something :)

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/bm3Lfcod/1/

For those seeking for a solution that works within a flexible parent container with a children that is flexible in both dimensions. eg. navbar buttons.

```
//the parent (example of what it may be)
div {
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
}

//The children
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

//text wrapper
span {
  display: table-caption;
}
```

Comment: Try giving that span any other `CSS` property you can give. Say a property which could cause `browser reflow`

Comment: browser reflow?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and none of the options here helped me. Some mail services do not support specified styles.
Here is my version, which solved the problem and works everywhere I checked:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="1">Gargantuan Word</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

OR using CSS:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:1px">Gargantuan Word</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this on a project where the client wanted the 3 word title on a different line. Basically your increase the spaces with CSS the use the white-space to separate the lines.

```css
    word-spacing:9999px;
    white-space: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add markup (e.g. a `span`) around each word then you can use CSS to insert a line break after each.

Note that the "content" we are inserting is `\a` which is hex for decimal 10 which is the newline character.

```css
.break-after-each-word > .word::after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="break-after-each-word">
  <span class="word">Foo</span>
  <span class="word">Bar</span>
  <span class="word">Baz</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Split the words and join them with a `<br>` tag.

Note 1: This is a non-CSS alternative solution.

Note 2: This is specific to my own specific problem and it works fine and I'm okay with the cons; i.e. more compute power needed, the addition of JavaScript and adding extra 
 tags between each word. Again, this works fine in my React.js project and I thought I'd share it in case someone finds it useful.

```
// @ts-nocheck
const HeadingCell = ({cell}) => {
  const splitHeading = (heading) => {
    const words = heading.split(' ')
    const joinedWords = words.join('<br>')
    return joinedWords
  }

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: splitHeading(cell.data.heading)}}></span>
}

export default HeadingCell
```

Answer (score -4):

In my case,

```
    word-break: break-all;
```

worked perfecly, hope it helps any other newcomer like me.

Comment: A -1 from me because this is an incorrect answer. This breaks the line at every character IF needed.