# What's the semantically correct way to break headings into lines?

Tags: html

I think (don't know why) that using `<br/>` is kind of bad...

```
<h1>My<br/>
multiline header - notice only first<br/>
line contains short word</h1>
```

Are there other suggestions?

**Update**
One of the lines will be shorter than the others

Comment: <br/> is kinda bad in h1 tag change h1 to p tag then its good :)

Comment: `h` represents a heading, or title, which in generally a targeted punchline - I'm not sure a multi-line heading is a good idea anyway. Wrapping is a different issue, though.

Comment: I think this is fine. AFAIK there isn't another way of doing it whilst ensuring the header contents are semantically contiguous

Comment: @jimy - no, no then it isn't a header anymore

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Per word breaking or per width (in terms of approximate character count or actual dimension)? If you clear this up, you'll get more relevant answers.

Comment: @Robert, I can do it with CSS. Bu what if I'll want to keep word "My", which is short, on it's separate line.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/common-idioms.html#sub-head

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## There is nothing wrong with <br />.

If you want to insert a line break on a unusual place, and you actually mean a line break, then **use** a line break.

Comment: Usually I would disagree with this as using markup to affect a design problem isn't ideal. However, there is simply no other way to get the desired effect using just CSS.

Comment: I agree with @MikeB but that's not HTML's problem, that's CSS's. HTML shouldn't have to sacrifice semantics to satisfy CSS; it should be the other way around. If the (front-end) Web was a pizza, HTML would be the crust and sauce, CSS would be the toppings, and JS would be the garlic salt that goes on top.

Answer (score 7):

### The usual HTML flow?

What seems to be wrong with the normal HTML flow? If your lines are too long and would like to make them shorter, you can always define width of your `H1` in CSS so you don't add markup to accommodate your design. Markup should be semantic, and CSS should provide the necessary visual appearance. Hence you can add width to your `H1` element and make it break the line as per set width.

```
h1
{
    width: 40em;
}
```

Also consider using text size related dimensions so you'll get better results (not too narrow not too wide) when using different head text sizes on different pages.

### When `<br/>` is fine?

Whenever you actually need to break your heading into a new line it's of course correct to use `<br/>`. Don't be afraid of using it if that's what it needs to be done on your heading. But for the purposes of head line overflows breaks are not used.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `<br />`'s in the  tag probably, the best way would be to contain it in a div that will wrap the H1 text:

```
<div style="width:50px;">
    <h1>My multiline header wraps now without br tags!</h1>
</div>
```

See this related question:

[Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element)

It's impossible in pure CSS, but with JavaScript it's possible.  I'd just go for the wrapping div though.

Comment: +1 - but: the only issue with this is font-rendering in different browsers. The OP may want the header to break in a particular place. Using a <br />, whilst not great, guarantees this.

Comment: @Richard yeah, but I still don't like putting `<br />` in header tags, it just feels unnatural, also some search bots might penalise or handle them weirdly.  I'd just try and avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: @Richard: If he wanted to break at a particular word, then there obviously should be a break. But only there. Not just to break it into single words.

Comment: it's design only consideration. designer want first word to be on it's separate line, and this word is only 4 letters long, whilst other flow I can control with CSS easily.