# Separate sentence to one word per line

Tags: css

Is it possible to separate sentence to one word per line with CSS ?

Input:

```
<div>Hello world foo bar</div>
```

Rendered output:

```
Hello
world
foo
bar
```

Setting width to for example `1px` is not desired.

Comment: just wondering, what's wrong with width:0 or 1px - why don't you want that?

Comment: Because of attached other styles to the text - for example background.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to use `display:table-caption;` to achieve this.

Here is the solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgKbg/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div>Hello world foo bar</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div{display:table-caption;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't teach your father how to make children. It is possible to accept answer after 15 minutes since question is added. ;-)

Comment: This actually only groups words based on the width of the longest word.

Comment: @JamesSouth - Can you share a fiddle with what you are referring above?

Comment: @InternalServerError - As per the situation of OP, the case is not table headers. Also, not sure why you would do this for table headers.

Comment: @NathanL I posted an answer as I wanted to explain it properly.

Comment: Giving a `padding` to this `div` makes it go useless. Say, if you want to style it.

Comment: best and standard I have ever seen

Answer (score 22):

Nathan's answer using `table-caption` is almost correct but misses out a key issue in that the sentence is only actually split by the longest word resulting in grouping of shorter words.

For example the following sentence:

> This trick groups and splits words in a sentence based on the longest word.

actually result in the following output. Note the grouping on `in a` and `on the` in the output.

```html
This 
trick 
groups 
and 
splits 
words 
in a 
sentence 
based 
on the 
longest 
word.
```

You can actually do it very easily by setting the `word-spacing` which has [excellent support](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-spacing).

Using that you can output the sentence correctly as follows:

```html
This 
trick 
groups 
and 
splits 
words 
in 
a 
sentence 
based 
on 
the 
longest 
word.
```

Here's a working code example you can run.

**Snippet**

```css
p {
  word-spacing: 9999rem;
}
p ~ p {
  /* Undo last assignment */
  word-spacing: unset;
  display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<h3>word-spacing</h3>
<p>
  This trick splits each word in a sentence
</p>
<hr/>
<h3>table-caption</h3>
<p>
  This trick groups and splits words in a sentence based on the longest word.
</p>
```

Comment: +1 For your efforts to further improve the answer. My answer was based on OP's scenario. You have provided an alternative which is "bit" different from what I have answered keeping in view OP's question.

Comment: Thanks! I stumbled across my solution after experimenting with yours.

Comment: This is the solution. Word spacing is where it's at. Get that table-caption out of here!

Answer (score -9):

You can set the width of the div to 1px, this will put each word on a new line

```
div {
    width:1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KjX4N/

Comment: Maybe you should give some requirements then, you question is not really specific, can we add extra html? Target seperate words is not possible in CSS

Comment: There is one reuirement: CSS without `1px` - everything is in the question.