# Line Break on Space

Tags: css, newline, whitespace

Is it possible to have CSS treat spaces as line breaks? I have HTML like:

```
<li>This and That</li>
```

I would like it to be displayed like:

```
This
and
That
```

Comment: Possibly look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element

Comment: can you use `javascript` instead of css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try styling it with

```
width: 0;
```

together with the default `overflow: visible`, it will produce that effect. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9PYL/)

But note that forcing overflow may produce [undesired behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/L9PYL/1/).

**Edit**: Using it together with `display: table` (instead of `block`) or `display: inline-table` (instead of `inline-block`) can fix those problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Good idea. However, I have a complex CSS layout (family tree rendered with lists) and this borks it all. I guess I will need to go with <br/> inserted server-side.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that with defined widths by doing

```
li {
    width: 100px;
    word-spacing: 100px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpJvr/)