# heading break for dynamic heading

Tags: html, css

I have a `heading` which is coming to my app from the API.

This is how I am binding it in my JS.

```
  _strInnerHtml += "<h5>" + value.test_name + "</h5>";
```

So I want to break the heading to the next line after the screen ends. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean 'break the line to the next line' ?

Comment: Sounds like your `h5` element is contained within an element which stretches beyond the width of the screen.

Comment: Do you mean wrap the text when it's overflows the container so it instead appears on two lines?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly exactly!

Corrected Velimir

Comment: try to set style property  word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: yes ui-matt, exactly what I wanted to say

Comment: @Ramkee for some reason, that didn't work

Comment: break-word works when you just type "dasfasdklfaslfkaj" and there are no words to brake on, try inspecting the element to figure out why it goes off the screen. Also try to set the `width` parameter of the element, you'll need to give it `display:inline-block` in order for that to work

Comment: let me try with `inline-block`, can't do inspect element as phonegap and coming from api so chrome won't work

Comment: Maybe this will be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking to style it with css you should do like this:

```
h5
{
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 100%;
}
```

And if this doesnt work try with the: `word-break: break-all;`