# How to add new line in ion-option tag?

Tags: ionic-framework

Need a new line after company name in a dropdown list.

I have tried everything, insert `<p>` & `<br>` tag as well.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>select</ion-label>
    <ion-select okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
    <ion-option value="1"> company1 address1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">company2  address1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">company3 address3</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="4">company4 address4</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
 </ion-item>
```

I want to show an address in the new line. I have tried an HTML tag also between company & address. company & address are two different texts.

After using the tag, it is showing in the same line.

Updated: I know the HTML tag won't work in ion-option. Is there anyone who faced the same thing in ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit awkward to inject html into an ionic element but you can get round it

css.

```
page-home {
    .select-text{
        white-space: normal;
        width: min-content;
        word-spacing: 9999px;
    }
}
```

[image]

good discussion on it [Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element)

hope this helps