# How to put 2 words one below the other when using css grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid, word-wrap

I have 2 words which need to be put one below the other regardless of the screen size.

The words **something** and **else** need to be on separate lines

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.colA {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.colB {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="colA">something</div>
    <div class="colB">something else</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/kq3sf6ae/

Comment: Between this 2 words can be another text? if not why you don't use a simple br? Or  `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` for the wrapper?

Comment: @Sfili_81 there cannot be other words in between, i cannot use break i can only modify classes given above

Comment: So the second column must have the word something [break with css] else?

Comment: Are the words constant or do they change?

Comment: one below the other ,something in one line and, else in the other and wont  change

Comment: If I understand well, you wish to replace space by `<br>` but my question is: it does not matter the number of word in this second column or you have specific case ?

Comment: I don't want to inject a br in between, is there a css solution to it, no js. I haven t included js tag in the question either which should give a clue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `word-spacing: 100vw;`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
}

.colA {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.colB {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="colA">something</div>
    <div class="colB">something else lt hhjjhhjjhh hhjjhhhjhbhbbbhhjjhhhjhbhbbbhhjjhhhjhbhbbhhjjhhhjhbhbbbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is huge copy of duplicate posted... Not worthy of 11k points