# How to break a new line after every word inside a span without using br

Tags: html, jquery, css

How do I break a new line after every **word** inside a `<span>` without using `<br>` tag. So it doesn't matter how long the word is, a word break will be applied after that word.

Say for example: `<span>apple pear</span>` pear should appear on next line.

Comment: Without using `<br/>` at all? Or without having to manually add them into the markup? (Aka, is programmatically adding line breaks with JS the goal?)

Comment: without <br> at all I was wondering if it is possible with css or jquery

Comment: You could use JavaScript to replace any spaces with a `<br/>`

Comment: Possible CSS solutions are available here: [Can CSS force a line break after each word in an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212909/can-css-force-a-line-break-after-each-word-in-an-element) (The `word-spacing` option is what I would probably suggest)

Comment: @phuzi OP doens't want to use <br />

Answer (score 3):

```
word-break: break-word;
word-spacing: 50000px; // set a maximum possible width of your parent width or simply a high number
```

This css will work for your situation.

```html
<span style="word-break: break-word;
    word-spacing: 50000px;">
    asd fgh qwe yui
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approach,

```css
span{
  width:0px;
  display:block;
  white-space:break-all
}
```

```html
<span>asd dfg hjk ert</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as below.

```css
span{
     display: table-caption;
}
```

```html
<span>apple pear</span>
```

Comment: Or without creating a seprate css you can use in this way <span style="display: table-caption;">apple pear</span>