# Formatting pluck('') output in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-9

just wondering how to format this output for a better view? (second picture). as you can see in the first picture the output from pluck('name') was like {Tidak Masuk Sekolah} {Terlambat}. check the pictures below

[image]

[image]

and this is my view, I'm using table

```xml
<div class="card-body">
  <h2 class="display-4 text-center">{{ $title }}</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive d-flex justify-content-center">
    <table class="table mx-9 my-6 table-borderless">
      <tr>
        <td>Nama Siswa</td>
        <td>{{ $counseling->student->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Kelas</td>
        <td>{{ $counseling->student->student_class->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Masalah yang dihadapi</td>
        @foreach ($counseling->problems->pluck('name') as $problem_name) {
          <td>{{ $problem_name }}</td>
        }
        @endforeach
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `@foreach()` doesn't use `{` and `}`; it should be `@foreach(...)`, then `@endforeach`. That is why you've got `{` and `}` in your output.

Comment: omg, sorry for my careless. then how to make the output like second picture with number and new row

Comment: @LanaSeptiana @foreach is essentially used to iterate (If needed) and render the data that is sent from the backend. To output it like the second picture you can use `<li>` tags thats wrapped inside an `ol` (Ordered list)

Comment: @Zeon its still in one line, i want make it in a new line every single word

Comment: and i was using {{ $loop->iteration }} for the number

Comment: Take a look at how `pluck` works - you can either split the words into a series of arrays for each works..or just use CSS.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68066573/4745869 doing it on the frontend would be a cleaner approach since you choose your mind you can change the CSS on the fly rather than the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ol` element to achieve that look.

```xml
<tr>
  <td>
    <p>Masalah yang dihadapi</p>
    <ol>
        @foreach ($counseling->problems->pluck('name') as $problem_name)
          <li>{{ $problem_name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Or

```xml
<tr>
  <td>Masalah yang dihadapi</td>
  <td>
    <ol>
        @foreach ($counseling->problems->pluck('name') as $problem_name)
          <li>{{ $problem_name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Depending on where you want the list to appear